# Simultaneity of Astronauts

Tags: time, existence

Let us image a spacecraft in fast orbit.  Since it took off its clock has lost several minutes relative to Earth time.  From the ground we can speak to the astronauts, although there is 1 second radio delay.  Aside from the signal delay we can say we are coexistent, talking, albeit in different frames and quite different clock time.  So is this coexistence an existential, experiential construct disconnected from the mathematics of physics?  i.e. Physical processes on the ground are happening at a different rate, so in what way are we coexistent with the astronauts?

***Restatement***

In physics the tangible reality is the radio signal, so ground crew and astronauts need coinciding future causal/light cones, and the signals take time to travel.  If the delays are known signals could be sent to multiple spacecraft to arrive 'simultaneously' - We can know they are receiving the signal 'right now' - in the present.  Also, there is a horizon of the present beyond the spacecraft, but physics is only concerned with what can be causally connected.  So physics ignores the 'now', but it *metaphysically* exists, doesn't it?  And is it not really the *only* thing that truly exists, (unlike memories of the past)?

[image]

[Images source: Quora](https://www.quora.com/If-block-universe-eternalism-theories-were-true-could-it-be-possible-that-people-arent-experiencing-the-same-moment-in-time-as-the-present-In-this-sense-we-might-be-interacting-with-other-peoples-future-or-past-self)

***Addendum*** (*edited*)

The 'coexistence' referred to in my question is simply 'absolute simultaneity' as described [here](http://polanco.jesuits-africa.education:8080/jspui/bitstream/123456789/228/1/Einstein%2C%20Relativity%20and%20Absolute%20Simultaneity%20%28Routledge%20Studies%20in%20Contemporary%20Philosophy%29.pdf): **Einstein, Relativity and Absolute Simultaneity**.  I quote from a [review](https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/einstein-relativity-and-absolute-simultaneity/) below.

> The astronomer Van Flandern contributes a highly readable essay on
> "Global Positioning System and the twins' paradox", arguing that GPS
> is "a practical realization of Lorentz's 'universal time', wherein all
> clocks remain synchronized despite being in many different frames with
> high relative speeds". In essence, the GPS system considers one frame,
> the local gravitational field (read, Lorentzian ether), to be
> privileged: here alone clocks tick at universal time, lending a new,
> technology-infused meaning to Lorentzian relativity.

Comment: We are "coexistent" with everything in our causal cone, as we can send and receive signals from there. What does it have to do with rates? However, this "coexistence" is entirely inferential, with mediation from physics and mathematics, it is not a "disconnected experiential construct", I think (what does that mean exactly?).

Comment: Disconnected meaning the ground crew and the astronauts are experiencing different physical environments; but they continue to coexist even if the astronauts orbit so fast they become frozen in time.  Or are we not coexisting when time dilates?  Does it start to concern what we mean by existing?  The experiential construct.

Comment: I think it concerns what we mean by *co*-existing in the spirit of [eternalism/presentism debate](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/presentism/). In relativity we are coexisting with the entire spacetime, the global simultaneity intuitions, that probably motivate your "coexistence" (existence "at the same time"?), are invalid there. What remains of them is just the possibility of causal interaction, which would restrict "coexistence" from the entire spacetime to our causal light cone. Arguably, we do not "*co*exist" with the part of it that we can never interact with.

Comment: @Conifold That is getting close to the heart of the matter.  Does anything contradict the 'horizon of the present' being unobservable, but actually real.  Physics says we can't see it so forget about it. i.e. from your interesting link, [Relativistic Physics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/presentism/#RelaPhys)  "Positing otherwise unnecessary unobservable structure—absolute simultaneity—does violence to Ockham’s razor."

Comment: So I'm asking, isn't the matter present in the "absolute simultaneity" in the "unobservable structure" actually the only physical reality?

Comment: Some further reading: [Ch.8 A defense of absolute simultaneity](http://polanco.jesuits-africa.education:8080/jspui/bitstream/123456789/228/1/Einstein%2C%20Relativity%20and%20Absolute%20Simultaneity%20%28Routledge%20Studies%20in%20Contemporary%20Philosophy%29.pdf)

Comment: It's not just Ockham’s razor. Reintroducing a privileged reference frame to define that "simultaneity" (that would be Lorentz's ether or equivalent) is quite ugly, it rips apart natural symmetries of the theory and its conceptual coherence. And for what, keeping another flat earth? Most physicists feel that to the extent that nature is "telling" us something through physics, it is telling us to let go.

Comment: "And for what"? - Simply to confirm that there is a real moment of simultaneity, which is the present.  Perhaps I should look into the [Machian shape dynamics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-theories/#RelaBestMatc) : "One way to understand the relationship between GTR and shape dynamics is that one trades the relativity of simultaneity but absoluteness of scales in the former theory, for absolute simultaneity but the relativity of scales in the latter."

Comment: What makes you think that there is such a "real moment of simultaneity" in the first place, and there is anything to "confirm"? Other than habits born of experience with *very* low speeds? That's the problem presentism is having currently: all sorts of conceptual contortions needed to fit a preconceived notion, with no good reasons to bother with the fitting.

Comment: Multiple spacecraft can use adjusted clocks so that their crews can be in sync, so the living moment can be synchronous too.

Comment: "Simultaneity" refers to the idea of two events at different locations happening at the "same time"--can you be specific about what pair(s) of events in your scenario you would consider as simultaneous? Are you considering the event of my sending the signal and the astronaut receiving it to be simultaneous, and the event of the astronaut sending a reply to be simultaneous with my receiving the reply, despite the delay we both experience?

Comment: @Hypnosifl Hi, I am saying the events are absolutely simultaneous, as with GPS synchronisation.  Some progress has been made since I first asked this question and the issue of absolute simultaneity has become clearer.  See my edited question addendum for clarification.

Comment: Which events are absolutely simultaneous in your astronaut example, though? GPS synchronization is just a simultaneity *convention*, one could program GPS satellites to respect many different possible simultaneity conventions which would give different answers about which pairs of events happened at the same time-coordinates. And the "relativity of simultaneity", saying that no simultaneity convention is "preferred" by the laws of physics, is built into relativity theory. So GPS provides no support for the idea of a unique objective truth about simultaneity (as in ch. 8 of the book you linked)

Answer (score 0):

Your example contains an internal fallacy, as follows:

For the spacecraft to have experienced a time dilatation onboard of several minutes due to special relativity, it cannot be only one light-minute from earth.

For a complete explanation of why, I suggest you post this to the physics stack exchange.

Comment: I think the physics perspective is that the ground crew and the astronauts are in different frames and their only point of knowable reality contact is the delayed radio signal (light cone).  I am trying to get beyond that to the awareness of the simultaneity/coexistence, for instance "I know they will be receiving my signal right now."  However, can 'simultaneous' be said when they are in different frames with different time flow?

Comment: Lol Physics Stack Exchange refers it back to Philosophy (or at least not Physics) : [How do we mathematically know for sure that absolute time is abandoned in relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/366152/36633)

Answer (score 0):

It's like information in physics, where it having been defined there as the inverse of entropy, can lead to confusion.

In relativity time hasn't been discovered to be absolute or not, it's been defined, as related to the speed light moves. That's also, the limit at which signal information can be transmitted between locations.

Physicists had to think harder and more precisely about information, in order to account for Maxwell's Demon. Relativity forced similar more precise thinking about time. So I ask you, what do you think time *is*?

> "What then is time? If no one asks me, I know what it is. If I wish to
> explain it to him who asks, I do not know." - St Augustine

More on time in philosophy here: [Can time be understood conceptually without experiencing it?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/82543/can-time-be-understood-conceptually-without-experiencing-it/82552#82552)

Comment: Actually I think time is a separate issue from 'the moment of existence', which is what Einstein declared as unobservable.  There is an amusing PDF about that here: [Science and the Unobservable](https://www.nature.com/articles/140963b0) (Nature, 1937).  However, absolute simultaneity is used for GPS; it can be calculated given knowledge of the topology.  Physically, it *is* what exists, regardless of how fast or slow time is flowing at a specific location.

Comment: So the 'moment' is the instantaneous configuration of everything.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen: Instanteneity is relative. We are finding rather than everywhere existing all-at-once, it's more like waves of types of change bouncing around, and we see intersections as causes, or objects. Have a look at [Is the idea of a causal chain physical (or even scientific)?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/70930/is-the-idea-of-a-causal-chain-physical-or-even-scientific/72055#72055) You might find the Loop Quantum Gravity picture of time as emergent interesting also.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen: "Absolute" simultaneity is not really absolute, it's [a convention](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/591436/83269) (albeit a fantastically convenient and useful convention).

Comment: @CriglCragl Hi. I see "Presentism and Quantum Gravity" http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/2308/ concludes: "Given that physics is currently moving in the direction of M theory and loop quantum gravity, presentism’s future prospects do not look good, at least from the standpoint of scientific realists who take current developments in quantum gravity as getting us close to a true account of reality. Nevertheless, based on the existence of potentially viable theories of fixed foliation quantum gravity, I conclude that presentism is compatible with our most fundamental physics – for now."

Comment: The conclusion of Michael Webermann's [About a Causal Theory of Time](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/10054/4/About_a_Causal_Theory_of_Time.pdf) (2013) reads : "We believe in the second law of thermodynamics and in the general theory of relativity and it turns out that if the principle of stable causality holds, we could use the entropy production to endorse a global time function which we may be able measure some day. Nevertheless, the notion of time is an ideal one and time might not belong to the things in themselves."

Comment: It requires the astronaut to experience the now.

Answer (score 0):

The crux of this question is that it is asking whether "really the only thing that truly exists" is what exists 'now', as, for instance, experienced in common by astronauts referencing a privileged frame.

To begin with, the 'now' that is experienced should be separated from the scientific 'now' of clock-time, such as now 3 o'clock. E.g. Heidegger's *Being & Time*, page 387-388

> That *Present* which is held in [Dasein's] authentic temporality and
> which thus is *authentic* itself, we call the "*moment of vision*".
> This term must be understood in the active sense as an ecstasis. ...
> The moment of vision is a phenomenon which *in principle* can *not* be
> clarified in terms of the "*now*" [dem *Jetzt*].  The "now" is a
> temporal phenomenon which belongs to time as within-time-ness: the
> "now" 'in which' something arises, passes away, or is present-at-hand.
> ... [As] an authentic Present or waiting-towards, the moment of vision
> permits us *to encounter for the first time* what can be 'in a time'
> as ready-to-hand or present-at-hand."

That should clarify the separation of the moment of experience from the scientific 'now' of synchronised GPS satellites, for instance.

In defining the scientific 'now' we need only to deal with clock-time and physical information.  However, this runs into problems with universality.

Re: "*In essence, the GPS system considers one frame, the local gravitational field (read, Lorentzian ether), to be privileged: here alone clocks tick at universal time*"

This specific conceptualisation of synchronised absolute time using calculated adjustment to clock-time depends on clock-time, which fails to be universal in a gravitational singularity, e.g. from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_singularity)

> A gravitational singularity ... is a condition in which gravity is so intense that
> spacetime itself breaks down catastrophically. As such, a singularity
> is by definition no longer part of the regular spacetime and cannot be
> determined by "where" or "when".

And from within a singularity, according to [Stefan Hensel's account](https://www.quora.com/Can-time-stop-at-the-singularity-of-a-black-hole)

> time doesn't stop at the singularity. Au contraire, it's accelerated
> to the max. What does stop is space.

So it is not possible to define a universal, synchronised manifold of simultaneity:  it is stymied by the asymptotes of singularities.